# Charge – Change currency

Tags: stripe, charge

I'm trying out Charge for a membership website, and need to change the currency to Singapore Dollar SGD. It is not listed as default currency in settings.

I've tried using {exp:charge:form plan_currency="sgd"} but it throws a "Currency - Not a valid currency" error.

I can't seem to find any other info in the documentation or here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by manually adding the currency in 3 separate files:

```
charge > mcp.charge.php
charge > models > charge_stripe_model.php
charge > language > english > lang.charge.php
```